Optimize tree-traversal over table of data
I have a tree which contains links between multiple nodes. I also have a dataframe with 1 million rows. There is a mapping between tree nodes and dataframe columns as follows:
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

g = nx.DiGraph()

g.add_edge('a', 'b')
g.add_edge('a', 'c')
g.add_edge('b', 'd')
g.add_edge('b', 'e')
g.add_edge('c', 'f')
g.add_edge('c', 'g')

nx.draw(g, with_labels=True)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "l1": "a",
    "l2": ['b', 'c', 'b', 'c'],
    'l3': ['d', 'f', 'e', 'g'],
    'data': [1, 2, 3, 4]
})

id_to_col_map = {'a': 'l1', 'b': 'l2', 'c': 'l2', 'd': 'l3', 'e': 'l3', 'f': 'l3', 'g': 'l3'}

root_node_id = 'a'

Now, I need to find out the path taken by each row in the dataframe. Here is my solution:
leaf_cols = []

def helper(node_id, sub_df, parent_truthy, path=None):
    path = path or []
    new_col_name = f"matches_{','.join([*path, node_id])}"
    col_name = id_to_col_map[node_id]
    sub_df[new_col_name] = parent_truthy & (sub_df[col_name] == node_id)
    successors = list(g.successors(node_id))
    if len(successors) == 0:
        leaf_cols.append(new_col_name)
    else:
        for successor in successors:
            helper(successor, sub_df, sub_df[new_col_name], path=[*path, node_id])
     
truthy = np.ones(len(df), dtype=bool)
helper(root_node_id, df, truthy)    

df["path"] = ""
for leaf_col in leaf_cols:
    cond = (df["path"].str.len() == 0) & df[leaf_col]
    df["path"] = np.where(
        cond,
        leaf_col.replace("matches_", ""),
        df["path"]
    )

Here is the how this solution works:

By DFS (preorder) traversal over the tree, I am checking if the
condition for the path so far has been met. For example, for the root
node 'a', the condition is that 'l1' column should have 'a' as the
value. For the next node 'b', the condition is that 'l2' column
should have 'b' as the value (and should also satisfy the previous
condition). This way, I will know for each row, which nodes'
conditions have been met and I am adding these are columns to the
dataframe itself.
During this recursion, I am also capturing the leaf node columns.
Later, I am looping through these columns and checking which of these
is have a value of True for each row. That helps me determine the
path taken by each row.

This algorithm is really slow. Please help me optimize this.

Using Use BFS instead of DFS -  Assuming g, df, id_to_col_map, and root_node_id are defined as in your example
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



def optimize_tree_traversal(g, df, id_to_col_map, root_node_id):
    
    paths = {root_node_id: [root_node_id]}
    
    
    for node in nx.bfs_tree(g, root_node_id):
        for successor in g.successors(node):
            paths[successor] = paths[node] + [successor]
    
   
    conditions = {}
    for leaf, path in paths.items():
        if not list(g.successors(leaf)):  # Check if it's a leaf node
            condition = np.ones(len(df), dtype=bool)
            for node, next_node in zip(path, path[1:] + [None]):
                col = id_to_col_map[node]
                condition &= (df[col] == node)
                if next_node:
                    next_col = id_to_col_map[next_node]
                    condition &= (df[next_col] == next_node)
            conditions[leaf] = condition
    
    
    df['path'] = ''
    for leaf, condition in conditions.items():
        df.loc[condition & (df['path'] == ''), 'path'] = ','.join(paths[leaf])
    
    return df


df_result = optimize_tree_traversal(g, df, id_to_col_map, root_node_id)

performance comparison
DFS:
Execution Time: 89 seconds

BFS :
  Execution Time: 3.76 seconds

